# Middleware to apply success callbacks to promises

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a bunch of API helper functions whose responses are treated individually, but also share standard successful / error callbacks. In case of a 401 response, user needs to be redirected. Alas, redirection is done via dispatch.

```
export default interpreter => (xhrRequest, callback) => {
    return xhrRequest
        .then((res) => {
            if(res.status === 401) {
            // Need a dispatch over here
            }

            interpreter(res, callback)
        });
};
```

That's the code I was going for as a wrapper function when I realized I'd need a dispatch I don't have access to.

Middleware seems like the way to go, but I can't wrap my head around how to go about it.

Note: redux-sagas are also an option.

[Best place to apply API response transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625791/best-place-to-apply-api-response-transformation)'s option #1 is what I'm trying to avoid having to do. I'd like to keep my API helpers separate from everything else, and not apply the same handler N times, where N is how many helpers I have.

Comment: Since there's no reply, in case anyone's wondering, I went the middleware way by giving actions the request and checking for its existence + handling it inside a middleware function. Works like a charm, just had to adapt the action creators. In any case, if anyone cares to reply how to do it differently, there's still no accepted answer.